# INetFwRules getting stuck getting the count

Tags: c++, windows-firewall-api

My code is getting stuck trying to get the count of a INetFwRules interface. The code below never returns or throws and just seems to wait on the Get_count() call. Any suggestion where to check are appreciated.

```
template <class TP, class T, class T2> long TestEnum<TP, T, T2>::count()
{
    long count = 0;
    HRESULT hr = pInterfacePtr->get_Count( &count );
    if( FAILED( hr ) )
        throw _com_error( hr );
        
    return count;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Use a debugger, a stack trace of the deadlocked call is a minimum requirement to get help.

Comment: I added the call stack I get when I check the dump that I have.